# How to remove a character from the middle of a string? Swift 4

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to remove a character in the middle of a string.

This is what I would like to do

```swift
let index = 4
let str = "abcdefg"
let strRemoved = str.remove(at: index) //Removes only character at pos 4
print(strRemoved) //prints 'abcdfg'
```

Comment: What's the problem? Note that indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Declare `var str = "abcdefg"` then `let strRemoved = str.remove(at: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at how you'd remove a character from the middle of `String` by looking at an example use case where we remove random letters from a string until it is empty.

---

**Method 1: Use `String.remove(at:)` to remove characters**

Here we use the method `String.remove(at:)` to select the character to remove.  Unfortunately, `String`s aren't indexed with `Int`, so you need to provide a `String.Index` value:

```
var str = "abcdefg"

while str.count > 0 {
    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< str.count)
    str.remove(at: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: randomIndex))
    print(str)
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> abdefg
> bdefg
> befg
> bfg
> bf
> f
> ```

---

**Method 2: Use `prefix()` and `dropFirst()` to construct a new `String`**

Alternatively, you could use `prefix()` and `dropFirst()` to select parts of your original `String` to construct a new `String`.  Both of these methods return type `Substring`, so it is necessary to call `String()` after concatenating the parts:

```
var str = "abcdefg"

while str.count > 0 {
    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< str.count)
    str = String(str.prefix(randomIndex) + str.dropFirst(randomIndex + 1))
    print(str)
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> abcdeg
> abcde
> acde
> acd
> cd
> c
> ```

---

**Method 3: Turn `str` into `[Character]`**

If you're going to repeatedly add, remove, and change characters, consider turning your `String` into an `[Character]`.  That is much easier to work with, because `[Character]` can be indexed with `Int`, and you can easily turn an `[Character]` called `chars` back into a `String` with `String(chars)`.

```
var str = "abcdefg"
var chars = Array(str)

while chars.count > 0 {
    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< chars.count)
    chars.remove(at: randomIndex)
    print(String(chars))
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> acdefg
> acefg
> aceg
> aeg
> ae
> a
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `String` collection's index it is not an Int but you can implement your own `remove(at:)` method that takes an `Int` as argument. Note that to remove an element from your collection you would need to declare it as variable:

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func remove(at offset: Int) -> Element? {
        guard let index = index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset, limitedBy: endIndex) else { return nil }
        return remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let index = 4
var abc = "abcdefg"

if let removedChar = abc.remove(at: index) { // Removes at pos 4
    print(removedChar) // prints 'e'
    print(abc) // prints 'abcdfg'
}
```